# Bootstrap dropdown not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Please find the jsFiddle below. I am trying to implement a simple Bootstrap dropdown button, but I am not able to achieve it.

Can someone please let me know what am i missing.

html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
$('#dropdownMenu1').dropdown('toggle');
```

Please find the fiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/rohan2911/BVZ6G/

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle needed jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BVZ6G/1

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery bootstrap.min.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```